# Can't get clothing to sit right on VRM after loading into VSeeFace

Tags: mesh, texturing

So i'm really new to blender, i thought i'd attempt to make a halloween costume for a VRM i use for vtubing and i got the springbones working and all the things, but when i load it i cannot get the fabric to not stick to my sides in a really shape disrupting way. i have tried quite a few things, but nothing seems to work. i assume it's weights or something but i have no idea how to fix it. where can i start?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you used automatic weights or have weight painted it manually? First image, is this the rest pose? If you have the character in a T-pose then the cloth should b also in a T-pose.

Comment: no, i can check to see if i can figure out automatic weights!

Comment: I think i did put automatic weights on it but i'll see if i can figure out how to check, the weight on it is all blue so there's no weight on it? i dont know. it's all a bit overwhelming lol

Comment: I ended up having to set a rest pose and then adjusting it thank you so much that worked exactly how i wanted!!! whew